# How to derive the Golden mean by using properties of Gamma function?

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, constants

The Golden mean known as $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

How could one show the Golden mean can be expressed as

$$
\frac{2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdots}{1\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 9\cdot 11\cdot 14\cdots}
$$

This is the limiting case of the Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction. But how would you prove this by using properties of Gamma function?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pardon if this is wrong but, could you clarify how  this is the limiting case of the Rogers Ramanujan continued fraction? I mean, $\phi$ is the continued fraction with $q=1$. The only similarity I can think of is this product formula for monic polynomials in terms of the gamma function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Calculating_products
, which could potentially be used to evaluate the $q$-series form of the RR continued fraction: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rogers-RamanujanContinuedFraction.html (third identity)

Comment: The limiting case of Rogers-Ramanujan continued fraction when q approaches i.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128952/golden-ratio-continued-fraction-gamma-function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the combination
\begin{align}f_N=\frac{\Gamma\left(N+\frac{2}{5}\right)\Gamma\left(N+\frac{3}{5}\right)}{\Gamma\left(N+\frac{1}{5}\right)\Gamma\left(N+\frac{4}{5}\right)}=
\frac{\left(5N-2\right)\cdot\left(5N-3\right)}{\left(5N-1\right)\cdot\left(5N-4\right)}f_{N-1}=\ldots=\\=
\frac{\left(5N-2\right)\cdot\left(5N-3\right)}{\left(5N-1\right)\cdot\left(5N-4\right)}\times\ldots\times \frac{8\cdot 7}{9\cdot6}\times\frac{3\cdot 2}{4\cdot1}f_0.
\end{align}
But $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{f_0}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)}=\frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}}{\sin\frac{\pi}{5}}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$
and $f_{N\rightarrow\infty}=1$ since
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\Gamma(x-a)\Gamma(x+a)}{\Gamma(x-b)\Gamma(x+b)}=1.$$
The infinite fraction representation follows. $\blacksquare$

Comment: That's quite inspiring! Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you please also show me how to prove the limiting case of Gordon's continued fraction when q approaches i by properties of Gamma function?                                                               i.e. sqrt(2) + 1 = (3*5*11*13*19*21*...)/(1*7*9*15*17*23*...) Thanks so much!

Comment: Exactly the same argument but starting with $f_N=\frac{\Gamma(N+3/8)\Gamma(N+5/8)}{\Gamma(N+1/8)\Gamma(N+7/8)}$.

Comment: Very Beautiful!

Comment: @TI82  Yes, certainly. But only reflection formula will not be sufficient. In addition, you will need to use [multiplication formula for the gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General). The comment space is too small, but I will be able to give the details if you post your question as a question.

Comment: @O.L. It is fine, I will try to work it out, thank you for the hint friend

Comment: @TI82 Then just an indication to save your time: multiply the denominator and numerator by the same product of three gamma functions such that in the denominator you have the product of multiplication formula with $m=5$. You will then notice that in the numerator you can apply (two times) reflection formula. The rest is trigonometry.