# Using Gamma function to show the limiting case of Gordon's continued fraction as q approaches i.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

A question similar to: [How to derive the Golden mean by using properties of Gamma function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374551/how-to-derive-the-golden-mean-by-using-properties-of-gamma-function)

The limiting case of Gordon's continued fraction when $q$ approaches $i$ yields:

$$\sqrt2 + 1 = \frac{3\cdot5\cdot11\cdot13\cdot19\cdot21\cdot\ldots}{1\cdot7\cdot9\cdot15\cdot17\cdot23\cdot\ldots} $$

How to derive this by using properties of the Gamma function?

Any help is appreciated!